# React: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/update'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing below issue after upgrading react version from 15.6.2 to 16.2.0

```
   React: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/update'
```

package.json

```
   "react": "^16.6.3",
   "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update react-addons-update to the latest version

```
   npm update react-addons-update
```

Comment: Hey, it is not working for me. Did you mean to install ```react-addons-update``` package?